# How do I determine which NAT type I have in GTA Online on the PC?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I decided to get out of Strict NAT type peasantry and set up a static IP and port forwards. But I can't check if it worked out, maybe it did, maybe it didn't, because the "You have a Strict NAT type" pop-up hasn't been popping up anymore, however, I have no idea whether I have a Moderate or Open NAT type. Please tell me the info is just hidden beneath layers and layers of mouse clicks and not just absent from the game.

Answer (score 2):

You can test your NAT Type to the Internet on this page here:

http://nattest.net.in.tum.de/

It runs a couple of tests and tells you the result after. However, please do note that you need to have [Java](https://java.com/en/download/) installed to run this test.